# lost ssh access to EC2 - Connection Timeout

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have an EC2 instance that is running Ubuntu 16.04 and have enabled ssh access through a Security Group on port 22.  Access was working but when I enabled my web server on it, access stopped.

My settings are as follows:

> ec2-{My IP}.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
>
> security group inbound rules (i changed to this to try to test and
>   restore access but it was previously my work IP which I could
>   establish access with)
>
> 80    tcp 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0 ✔
>
> 22    tcp 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0 ✔
>
> VPC and Subnet associated with the instance vpc-UNIQUEID
>
> subnet-UNIQUEID
>
> Network ACL (again, made it less restrictive temporarily to restore
>   access  11 - ALL TCP - TCP (6) - ALL - 0.0.0.0/0 - ALLOW

I've gone as high access as possible but still don't get access.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure there's no VPC/Security Group issue (you can still try with `sudo nmap -Pn <the ip address of your ec2 instance>`, then there's not much you can do. Your options are:

1. Restore to working state from a snapshot (if you have one)

   - create a volume from the snapshot
   - detach the non-working volume
   - attach the restored volume
2. Get access to the ec2 instance's volume and fix your issue

   - create a volume in the same region, same availability zone
   - detach the volume from the problematic instance
   - attach the volume to the new instance
   - mount it to `/mnt/something`
   - fix the issue - validate `sshd_config`, view local firewall rules (`uwf` maybe)

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for the suggestions.  The instance IS up and running because I can hit the public IP on port 80 and get a default web server response.  I just can't SSH. I DID also change uwf before I lost access on the box but only to enable http access while setting up the web server. Could that be my problem?  If I had a firewall problem wouldn't it just deny me rather than timeout?

Comment: You need access to the machine to figure that out. The only way to do it is to attach the volume to 2nd instance, mount it and review config files.

Comment: Gotcha. let me give that a shot

Comment: Ended up just blowing it up and building a new one.  Was faster in the end

Comment: That's an option if you can afford losing the data you have on the EC2 instance :)